# What is the benefit of the question preview box?

Tags: discussion, markdown-preview

What is the benefit of using the preview just below the question entry box? I don't see any.

Comment: I'm guessing you are having javascript problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preview window shows the final outcome of your html-coded post. It lets you test if your post will be displayed alright.

Answer (score 3):

So that you immediately see how your super ninja formatting is not being parsed correctly, enabling you to make it less super ninja without having to press a Preview button?

Answer (score 1):

So you can see what we will see.

Think of it as an embarrassment prevention mechanism with a real-time feedback loop.